# CodeIgniter controller doesn't recognize function

Tags: model-view-controller, codeigniter-4

This is something strange.

The controller function called product just doesn't work, but any other name works. See the following code:

```
namespace App\Controllers;

class Shop extends BaseController {

    public function index() {
        return view('shop');
    }
    
    public function asdf(){
        return view('product');
    }

    public function product(){
        return view('product');
    }
}
```

Calling the function `asdf` (or whatever name it is), works. But I get a 404 if I call the `/shop/product`.

How to explain (and hopefully solve) it?

Comment: Your question is tagged Codeigniter 3, but is it really CI4?  `BaseController` is from CI4, I think?  What routes do you have set up?

Comment: True. Anyway, do you have any thoughts on my issue?

Comment: Do you either have routes setup for the `/shop/product` URI or have auto-routing turned on

Comment: On a fresh CI 4.1.3 Installation it "Works for Me" with only default "out of the box" routes set. So you have a routing issue? Can you show the relevant parts of your config/routes.php. With the code you have provided so far I cannot replicate the error you are seeing.